# Extracting Salt out of Jasypt Digest

Tags: java, jasypt

I am using Jasypt to encrypt user's password. From my understanding, Jasypt appends the salt to the digest. I want to be able to extract the salt from that digest and save it in a db so that I can have the encrypted password and the salt on separate fields. I've looked at their documentation and there doesn't seem to be a a way to do this.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to store the salt and the digest separately, rather than using the value produced by jasypt?

Comment: I am guessing that I don't need to but really for portability. I have an existing user table that I will need to import. In that table, the salt is in a different column. I would like to follow the same approach.... do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: You wouldn't need to, if you're _only_ using jasypt because you can just use its `checkPassword` or `matches` methods against that single value. Were your existing digests computed with something other than jasypt? Are you planning on manually computing a hash to compare against the new jasypt value when authenticating a user? In other words, how are you reconciling the legacy digests side-by-side with the new ones?

Comment: Yes, it was computed using something other than Jasypt.